# Troubleshooting PWM circuit

Tags: pwm, attiny

I have constructed the following circuit on a breadboard and all functions as it should with no issues.

However, each time I solder this project onto a perf board, the same issue arises. The LED starts bright then goes dim upon powering up. Then I get no functionality. It is an cree 3 Watt LED that uses two buttons, a TIP31, a 5V supply and a digispark ATtiny85. The draw is 600 mA maximum as measured when connected to bread board.

[image: easyEDA schematic]

What I've done:

- Measured 5V at input pins from buttons. Both check.
- Reprogrammed the ATtiny after assembly.
- Checked continuity on perf board to input output pins and power.
- Power the LED directly, works fine.

Perhaps the digispark is that sensitive to solder heat? The transistor is a bad selection?

Comment: LED? What LED? I don't see any.

Comment: Assuming the LED is on the "Load" pins, what resistor or current limit is in series with it? If the answer is "none", then your breadboard is making such crappy connections that it supplies enough resistance to protect the LED, while a decent soldered version destroys the LED as you would expect. If the aim is to use the PWM to limit the LED current, then you need to monitor the LED current somehow anh not turn the PWM up above the rated current.

Comment: This is a larger led lamp. I have verified it's functionality.

Comment: anything get hot? PSU? LED, TIP31A?

Comment: If it's a LED *lamp* with its own current limiting, and it survives the full 5V rail, then look into the dissipation in Q1 - does it need heatsinking?

Comment: What is the 5V supply, exactly? Can you monitor its voltage with an oscope in the first milliseconds of start up? What's the voltage at the base of Q1 look like (at useful moments to check it?)

Comment: the 5V supply is currenly my bench power supply set to 5V with 600 mA set as limit. A few seconds after the digispark initializes, the light starts bright then dims down to zero.

Comment: @jaunty - I see that you have given some info (thanks for that), but there is still lots of missing info needed for efficient troubleshooting e.g. you have not answered the questions from *Tony Stewart* nor all the questions from *jonk*. I have some other areas where I could ask questions too. However, if you don't reply to questions, then some of us will not help you, because we would be wasting our time if you don't answer questions. In short: Either please answer *all* the questions which are asked to you, or clearly state that you will *not* answer questions.

Comment: @SamGibson I am working on it. Connecting oscope etc to measure at Q1.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Nothing gets hot. It only flickers on for a very short moment.  The circuit functions fine and normally on the breadboard. It only fails once I solder everything onto the perf.

Comment: @jaunty Are you using perf board with printed traces, and are you using those traces in your LED power path? Assuming a 1oz copper trace 2mm wide, you have the rough equivalent of a 34AWG wire, for which Wikipedia says the current rating is 300mA.  If your circuit works fine on a breadboard, I would assume the perf board is somehow to blame.  A significant trace resistance could drop too much voltage for the transistor to stay saturated when you also add the diode drop.  The LED might flicker on power-up because there is *just enough* voltage before the trace heats up and its resistance rises.

Comment: @Alex it is a through-hole. I am using wire.

Comment: @jaunty Are you using the same transistor as the one on your breadboard? Read Tony Stewart's explanation below. You could have a large variance in hFE (beta) which is causing the transistor to function in the linear region.

Comment: @Alex using a PCB trace calculator, a 2mm trace is perfectly happy with currents of 1 amp with distances over 150mm (6"). Don't confuse wire gauge with trace equivalence. Both have different properties one must take into account when calculating.

Comment: @MisterTea yes same transistor.

Comment: One thing you haven't answered, is what LED are you using? From your circuit, you have no current limiting which leads me to believe you have an LED without internal limiting and your soldered project has less resistance than an old/dirty breadboard which is causing problems. Post the LED part number or a link to the product page from which you purchased it. Then we can better help you.

Comment: Thanks Mister Tea, unfortunately I don't know the exact product, but it is a 3W LED that I salvaged from another part. Before doing so I measured the voltage and current at max.

Comment: @jaunty Is this a high power LED for lighting, e.g. a white led? Or is it a little LED for indication? Simple test, but have you tried adding a resistor in series with the LED? Try a 220Ω resistor and see what happens. You may also want to try a different LED. 600mA is a lot of current for an LED. That's 3 watts. You would usually such a high power LED powered from a constant current source.

Comment: @MisterTea it is a white LED. I will try 220 ohm resistor and report back. Constructing a new circuit. Thank you all for the discussion.

Comment: @jaunty My guess is your LED is not internally current regulated. Breadboards can sometimes develop oxidation and lose mechanical connection. This can cause unwanted resistance which makes your circuit appear to work. Then once hard wired, that LED is free to short the entire project once the transistor drives to saturation. This is why it glows bright to dim then off. Note, your LED might glow very dimly with 220Ω so don't freak out. You can decrease the resistance once you verify that the circuit works. You can also implement a constant current controller with your ATtiny85 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not understanding the transistor datasheet for hfe vs Ic/Ib when saturated and you are operating in the linear region resulting in poor switch control or current control.

If this is a LED with a heatsink rated for 600mA then it could be rated for 2-3W and will have a Vf ~3V depending on power rating and temperature.

The TIP31A is a power NPN with a strong attenuated hFE as Vce drops below 2V where hFe~100.

For effective control, you should saturate the NPN hard to <<1.2V (pref0.4V) and not rely on the Rb value and uncontrolled Vce vs hFE drop.

Thus for Ic=600mA , choose Ic/Ib=50 thus Ib=12mA then

**- R3=(5-1.4)/12mA= 300 Ohms**
  - next allow for a >= 0.8V drop (5-1.2-3.0) with a series R to LED or 1.25 Ohms rated >=1 Watt or use 8x 10 Ohm 1/4W R's in parallel.

If Vce <=0.6V then recalculate Rs and go from 1.25 towards 3 Ohms.
Then test and measure LED temperature with finger. If it is too hot to touch, you need a better heatsink.

This is a case where Rb and Rc are critical choices for driving a 3V diode from a 5 V supply, and frankly a Mosfet is easier with an RdsOn <<0.1 Ohm @1A.

This device also has an equivalent Rce that varies with Ic when Vce is saturated. Vbe must also be saturated and for most devices this ranges around Ic/Ib =20 but yet most devices , unlike this one, are rated for Vce(sat) @ Ic/Ib=10 and more expensive devices up to 50.

[image]

Here from the table, I compute Rce as follows:

- Vce(sat)=1.2V @ Ic=3A, Ib=375mA or Rce=1.2V/3A= 0.4 Ohms

  - this uses an Ic/Ib = 8 , lower than most.
  - if we design around a ratio of 20, Rce will rise as well as Vce
  - if we design around the hFE=100, then Vce is no longer saturated and Vce=2V at 1A (typical not worst case) here Rce = 2V/1A = 2 Ohms

    > Thus we can conclude as a switch best case with higher drive current than you are using Rce starts around 2 Ohms and rises sharply by an order of magnitude with insufficient base current, making the LED dim as Vce rises.
    >   [image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I will modify the circuit and try this. Do you have any explanation as to why my circuit works fine on the breadboard?

Comment: If you measure Vce , and Vled on both this should explain it.